# Google Maps API v.3 - Cannot display infowindow or when I do the center of the map is at the design location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a small problem with Google Maps' API v.3.
I get the location address from a  MySql db and try to send it dynamically to GMaps.
This works OK, but I cannot seem to open a "infowindow".
If messed with the code a little bit but the closest I've got to a solution was the infowindow open but the map centered on the defining position and not the actual one. I've searched through different sites but couldn't find an appropriate advice. Maybe I'm mixing v.2 and v.3 but as far as I can see it doesn't seem to be so. This is my first look at Google's API so please be patient.
All of the code is from examples:

```
  var marker;
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.696492,23.326011);
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address = "Milano 20099";
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          // alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<strong>I will be here!</strong><br/>Milano 20099'});
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move your info window open method to the geocoder success callback function. The geocode request can take a while to respond and you are trying to open an info window before the geocoder returns marker position. So your code should be as follows:

```
var marker;
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.696492, 23.326011);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom : 9,
                    center : latlng,
                    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                }
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

                map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = "Milano 20099";
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address' : address
                }, function(results, status) {
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map : map,
                            position : results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content : '<strong>I will be here!</strong><br/>Milano 20099'
                });


                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    } else {
                        // alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });

            }
```